# Inequality error possibly. How are two inequalities equal?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

Notation: $\underline{x}\in \Bbb R^n,||\cdot||_p =\left(\sum \limits_{i=1}^n |\cdot|^p\right)^{\frac1p}$

---

$$||\underline{x}||_p\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^n |x_i + y_i|^{(p-1)q}\right)^{\frac1q}+||\underline{y}||_p\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^n |x_i + y_i|^{(p-1)q}\right)^{\frac1q}$$

$$=\left(||\underline{x}||_p+||\underline{y}||_p\right)\left[\left(\sum \limits_{i=1}^n|x_i + y_i|^p\right)^{\frac1p}\right]^\frac pq$$

> How are these equal. The factorisation, and the $\frac1q =\frac1p\frac pq$ both make sense. The change from $(p-1)q\to p$ I don't understand.

The next step after this is:

$$\left(||\underline{x}||_p + ||\underline{y}||_p\right)||\underline{x}+\underline{y}||_p^{p-1}$$

Perhaps the bridging step between these is all that is wrong(and then the result still follows from the first step), but I can't see how to bridge these otherwise.

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are conjugated exponents : $1/p+1/q=1$ wich is equivalent to $p+q=pq$.

Comment: @Patissot Oh f. me. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Since $p\gt 0$, $q\gt 0$ are dual indices, we have$$\frac1p+\frac1q = 1$$

and hence $$q+p=pq$$

This coupled with the factorization, and the obvious fact that $\frac1q=\frac1p\frac pq$, completes the equality.

Comment: moderators feel free to set this to accepted

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite here my comment so you can accept it as an answer.

Since $p$ and $q$ are conjugated exponents we have $1/p+1/q=1$. By multipliying by $pq$ this is equivalent to $q+p=pq$.

We can also easyli check that $(p-1)/p=1/q$.